# What Autodesk platform to use for creating an Asp.net website to generate Drawings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autodesk

I need to implement for a customer an Asp.net website in which he will enter the dimensions and onclick of a button a drawing will be generated. Its my first Autodesk project so just need some info regarding what to search on google. After researching for a while I came to know about Autodesk 360 and BIM. Am I correct or do I need some other development platform. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be wary of the licensing here. being on asp.net it mean for them that their library will be available to all. this license is very very expensive. You are basically giving the opportunity to create CAD to everyone on the planet.

My solution i had to go with is buy 1 licence +/- 3000$ and installed it on a server then you create an app locally on the server that will pool from a database the requests and pipe them so you only have a single license at a time and them use the _saveas command and save it locally. then once the file has been created by autocad locally THAT file is totally legal to send around without licensing issue.

So you page can just push in database the data, attach a callback to let the user do what he wants. once the process is finish have it trigger the callback and the client will go get the file and download locally.

Comment: i did use Autocad 2012. i'm not sure if 360 is just a new name or another product. I'm no expert in that and where i work now we are using mostly solidworks

Comment: Just letting you know that i had test machine that i ran scripts for autocad on version 2000 and 2006 which worked perfectly. But small difference in Autocad 2010 commands force you to change your code a little bit.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear of the requirements earlier. I came to know that I will have to use web services(WCF maybe) to invoke Inventor specific commands residing on the server from the client.Now I m just confused how to get it started. The client does not have to generate any new drawings. Client can only provide his dimensions, scale etc for the pre existing designs. Give me some idea if you have any. Any help is appreciated. Ty

Comment: well for scaling an such you do not required to use autocad libs. all you need is simple script. a text file is enough. In short you can call from WCF a process start of autocad passing a text file containing autocad command. in your case you have a block i presume with scale on X,Y. all you need is the block insert command that look like : `INSERT [block name] X,Y Xscale, YScale` then call a `_saveas` and recuperate that file in a memory stream and send it to client add as byte[] and on the other side simpl save as .dwg and your done

Comment: you can also create parametrize blocks in autocad but i don't know how, when it was required a drafter made them for me.

Comment: Also if you plan on only using script command you ONLY require LT version of autocad which is much less expensive than Full versions.

Comment: thx man this is exactly wat I was looking for. Btw do u have any tutorial link for this? I have been searching for all over google but couldnt find many

Comment: i learned it on the fly. you best bet is asking an autocad drafter. That's how i learned 90% of the commands. He made us most of the 5000+ blocks and he configured a DWG for company standard dimensions, layouts and all. I created the software that generate the script, run them in autocad and email the user once they are done a PDF version and/or DWG

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take a look at the AutoCAD I/O web service. As it says on https://developer.autodesk.com/api/autocadio/, it allows developers to run AutoCAD scripts remotely and enable them to process DWG files at cloud scale. You can create an AutoCAD script or use one of our sample scripts, then point the AutoCAD I/O web service to the DWG files and finally run your script on the DWG files. AutoCAD I/O loads the DWG files, then run the script on each file. Upon completion, AutoCAD I/O saves the output to your specified location. AutoCAD I/O, as represented in the graphic, is storage agnostic—input and output files are not stored in AutoCAD I/O. Based on your choice of web storage; AutoCAD I/O is able to connect to it over HTTP.

You can find detailed information as well as code samples on https://developer.autodesk.com/api/autocadio/#

Answer (score 0):

It may be a old post...

But Autodesk released the AutoCAD I/O web API. This allow you to invoke a running AutoCAD on the cloud to create drawing or batch processing .DWG files. Then download the results.

There is also a Viewer API to view these drawings. No installation required.

See keys and documentation at http://developer.autodesk.com